# How to encode an NSDecimal?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I can only guess, but please correct me if I am wrong:

```
[encoder encodeValueOfObjCType:@encode(NSDecimal) at:&theDecimal];
```

where encoder is an instance of NSCoder.

But one thing is strange: Why is there no key to provide? How would I get that back then, without a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Again* at the very top of NSDecimalNumber's documentation, it states that it conforms to the NSCoding protocol, which means you can put it into an NSCoder the normal way:

```
[encoder encodeObject:theDecimal forKey:@"aKey"];
```

Edit: Whoops, I see you meant NSDecimal, not NSDecimalNumber. My bad. Still, a very simple way would be to wrap the NSDecimal in an NSDecimalNumber and store it that way.

Comment: Wrapping it to NSDecimalNumber is a good idea. At this point I could live with the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The old non-keyed coding protocol requires you to extract the keys in the same order as you encoded them.